# What is better Orange.data.Table or Pandas for data manage in python?

Tags: pandas, data-mining, libraries, orange

Iam doing data mining and i dont know if going to use Table or Pandas? 
any information for select the most suitable library for manage my dataset  going to be welcome. Thank for any  answer that help me in this.

Comment: You shouldn't ask opinion based questions on SO. However I think you should do some research using a search engine (e.g. Duckduckgo) and find out what is best for you. They are both good libraries but Pandas is the most popular.

Answer (score 1):

I am an Orange programmer, and I'd say that if you are writing python scripts to analyze data, start with numpy + sklearn or Pandas.

To create an `Orange.data.Table`, you need to define `Domain`, which Orange uses for data transformations. Thus, tables in Orange are harder to create (but can, for example, provide automatic processing of testing data).

Of course, if you need to interface something specific from Orange, you will have to make a `Table`.